Converting a large text file with inconsistencies into a data frame in R
I have a very large text file with tens of thousands of rows and around a hundred columns. The columns in the text file are stored based on character position. 1-20 is column1, 21-59 is column2, etc. Each row is around 1800 individual characters long. My current code is working how I want it to for about the first 70,000 rows. However, this particular file has some random rows that do not follow the pattern. These lines throw off the program and it doesn't read the rest of the lines. All the regular rows start with a 12 digit long identification number while the bad rows look like this.
00 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 02 94 00 00 00 00 00 00 N
The bad rows are not all identical and they appear at random intervals. Is there an easy way I can filter out these bad lines so that the program will read all the lines in the file? Thanks!
Currently my code looks like this:
df1 <- readLines("txtfile.txt")

df2 <- read.table(text=gsub("(.{1800})", "\\1 ", df1, perl=TRUE), header = FALSE, sep = "\r")

df3 <- separate(df2, V1, c('all my columns names'), sep = c(20, 62 , 85, etc),  remove = TRUE, convert = TRUE)


Can you be more specific about the pattern shared by the bad lines?  For example, is starting with "00" and 10 repeats of "000" a necessary and sufficient condition for dropping lines? (Or, having any spaces at all in the first 12 places?) (once you drop these lines, read.fwf() or readr::read_fwf() might be useful ...)

Are the good rows 12 digits id number always followed by a letter?

@BenBolker The bad lines don't follow a pattern. They just don't follow the pattern the good lines follow. Some start with just a single "0" some  and have nine "000". It's tricky because they don't follow any pattern.

@RuiBarradas The 12 digit id numbers are not followed by a letter. The first column is 20 characters. The first 12 are numbers and the last 8 are spaces.

@BenBolker Yes, The lines without the 12 numeric values at the beginning are all bad.

Maybe something like the following can solve the problem. Untested.
Package readr has functions to read large files in chunks and execute a callback function on each chunk. The callback function below extracts the characters 13 to 20 from each row and checks whether they are all blanks. If yes, the row is considered good and returned to caller.
In the end you have a character vector of the good rows. This can be read in a way similar to the read.table call in the question.
good_rows <- function(x, index) {
  s <- substr(x, 13L, 20L)
  i <- which(s == rep(" ", 8L))
  x[i]
}

# keep this value small to save memory
chunk_size <- 8L*1024L
con <- file("txtfile.txt", open = "rb")
good_text <- readr::read_lines_chunked(
  con,
  callback = DataFrameCallback$new(good_rows),
  chunk_size = chunk_size)
close(con)


I am getting this error.  Error in private$callback(data, index) : unused argument (index) I am not seeing the index argument in the documentation for the function

@ckwoff try adding an argument like I've done now, see the edit.

Something like:
df1 <- readLines("txtfile.txt")
df1 <- grep("^[0-9]{12}", df1, value = TRUE)

should extract the lines that start with 12 numeric values. @RuiBarradas's answer is certainly more efficient, but my guess is that this solution will be good enough for files that are "only" a few tens of thousands of lines long.
